# How to use value of php variable after execution in another file

Tags: php, android, mysql, database-connection

I am working on an android app on which I take Application ID and Applicant Name from the user as an input value for authentication which is matched from an MYSQL database using PHP to get to the next screen on connection success

**login.php**

```
<?php

session_start();

require "conn.php";

$user_name = $_POST["user_name"];
$user_id = $_POST["id"];

$mysql_qry = "select * from complaints where Applicant_Name = '".$user_name."' and Complaint_ID like '".$user_id."';";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $mysql_qry);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){

     $_SESSION["username"] = "$user_name";
     $_SESSION["userid"] = "$user_id";

    echo "Login Success";
}
else {
    echo "Login Not Success";
}
?>
```

Now on next screen, I want to show the content related to that particular Application ID and Applicant Name for which I want to use the value of variable $user_name  and $user_id from login.php in WHERE part of query of content.php to fetch the particular data I require.

Right now I am using the code below which is working fine right now but I want to use the value of $user_name and $user_id to use in WHERE part of content.php query

**content.php**

```
 <?php

session_start();

require "conn.php";

$username = $_SESSION["username"];
$userid = $_SESSION["userid"];

 //creating a query
 $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT Complaint_ID, Applicant_Name, Category, Subject, Description FROM complaints WHERE Complaint_ID = '".$userid."' AND Applicant_Name = '".$username."'");

 //executing the query 
 $stmt->execute();

 //binding results to the query 
 $stmt->bind_result($id, $name, $cat, $sub, $desc);

 $complaint = array(); 

 //traversing through all the result 
 while($stmt->fetch()){
 $temp = array();
 $temp['Complaint_ID'] = $id; 
 $temp['Applicant_Name'] = $name; 
 $temp['Category'] = $cat; 
 $temp['Subject'] = $sub; 
 $temp['Description'] = $desc; 
 array_push($complaint, $temp);
 }

 //displaying the result in json format 
 echo json_encode($complaint);

?>
```

On android there is no issue every thing is working fine its the PHP side I need Help.

Comment: ok where you get error in php .... explain

Comment: '*On android there is no issue every thing is working fine its the PHP side I need Help.*' - Help us help you by provided any errors. Is error reporting enabled? Have you checked the logs? What have you tried to solve the "issue"?

Comment: there is no error in it what I am asking is how to use value of variable $user_name and $user_id of login.php in the WHERE part of content.php file

Comment: use session for that in php @TanishqShastri

Comment: so should I replace $user_name and $user_id with $SESSION["$user_name"] and $_SESSION["$user_id"] respectively ?

Comment: You are wide open to SQL injections : you **MUST NOT** use raw user input into your queries ! please use prepared statements like in the content.php file. Also you should not mix procedural and object oriented style for mysqli

Answer (score 0):

I think first you need to change your select query in login.php, you should use '=' instead of like

```
$mysql_qry = "select * from complaints where Applicant_Name like '$user_name' and Complaint_ID like '$user_id';";
```

to

```
$mysql_qry = "select * from complaints where Applicant_Name='".$user_name."' and Complaint_ID='".$user_id."' ";
```

and need to store that $user_name and $user_id in session and use that session values on content.php like below

In login.php set values like below

```
 if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
   $_SESSION['name']=$user_name;
   $_SESSION['id']=$user_id; 
   echo "Login Success";
 }
```

Dont forget to start session at the top of both files

In content.php file use below query

```
 $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT Complaint_ID, Applicant_Name, Category, Subject, Description FROM complaints WHERE Complaint_ID = '".$_SESSION['id']."' AND Applicant_Name = '".$_SESSION['name']."'");
```

Comment: please do not propose a code that is vulnerable to sql injections. at least you must mention that the vars needs to be escaped properly or used in prepared statements

Comment: using session variable in content.php is not working. after login.php it gives a blank screen but using actual hard code application name and id is working. Maybe it's not taking the value from login.php to use in content.php I used proper code which you have provided.

Answer (score 0):

you can use PHP $SESSIONS to handle this. For your `login.php` do as below

```
    <?php
session_start();
require "conn.php";
$user_name = $_POST["user_name"];
$user_id = $_POST["id"];
            //your codes
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
         echo "Login Success";
     //just add this two sessions
         $_SESSION["username"] = "$user_name";
         $_SESSION["userid"] = "$user_id";
      } else {
      echo "Login Not Success";
             }
            ?>
```

Then at `content.php` perform a check on the sessions, if successful? get the values stored in the `$SESSIONS[]` when the login was successful.

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    if (isset($_SESSION['userid'])) {
//if succesfully set, get the values stored sessions.
        $username = $_SESSION['username'];
        $userid = $_SESSION['userid'];
//just echo to check if set output results are correct
    echo "sessions were set successfully username is $username and userid is $userid";
    }else{
    echo "was unable to set sessions";
    }
   require "conn.php"
//creating a query
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT Complaint_ID, Applicant_Name, Category, Subject, Description FROM complaints WHERE Complaint_ID = '$userid' AND Applicant_Name = '$username'");  
//Rest of your codes
        ?>
```

For more information you can visit https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp.
Sessions are available across all php pages so you can pick them from any where you want and information stored is not saved in the users computer.

Comment: using session variable in content.php is not working. after login.php it gives a blank screen but using actual hard code application name and id is working. Maybe it's not taking the value from login.php to use in content.php I used proper code which you have provided.

Comment: sorry I missed something out change $SESSIONS to $_SESSION, I forgot the underscore "_" let me edit the post

Comment: also its not a good idea to use like statement for login purposes it might return undesirable results and assign wrong variable or session. practice use of equal to = sign.

Comment: its still not working. **Please See the updated php code in post after your given suggections**

Comment: I am still getting a blank screen from this code but using actual hard code application name and id is working fine

Comment: add isset function to check if sessions were set and output them to check if they are the right values. have edited the code on how to do this hope this time it works.